# How to save every url in a Youtube Channel?

Tags: python, pytube

I want to save every url in .txt file.

```
from pytube import Channel
from pytube import YouTube
import pytube
import numpy as np

c = Channel('https://www.youtube.com/c/MrBeast6000/videos')

for url in c.video_urls[:1]:
    np.savetxt('Python.txt',url)
```

but i get "Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead" error. Python.txt file is created but its empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly write the URLS to a file from the collection without using numpy!

```py
...
with open("Python.txt", "w") as fh:  # begin a new file, clobbering existing
    for url in c.video_urls[1:]:     # probably intended 1:, not :1
        fh.write(f"{url}\n")         # write url and append newline char
```

Comment: Not the most intuitive. Use a loop, and call write for each url. It doesn't have to build a large string in memory, and it's easier to comprehend (in my opinion).